# guardmalloc what are those warnings and how do I get rid of them?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

GuardMalloc: Allocations will be placed on 16 byte boundaries.
GuardMalloc:  - Some buffer overruns may not be noticed.
GuardMalloc:  - Applications using vector instructions (e.g., SSE or Altivec) should work.
GuardMalloc: GuardMalloc version 18
(gdb)

all of the sudden those guardmalloc messages appears in the console window. What's the cause and how do I get rid of it? Mostly because the application behaves weird after those appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have intentionally enabled GuardMalloc to find memory errors?  If so, these appear simply because GuardMalloc is being used (as shown by http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/guardmalloc.3.html ).

What do you mean by "behaves weird"?  What symptoms appear?

Comment: I must have activated during my explorations of the IDE. Not sure how I can benefit from it but for now I'll shut the option off.

I just found 'n fixed a memory leak, the weirdness was caused by that.
Thank you for taking care of my question.

Comment: GuardMalloc's purpose (if I'm not mistaken) is to make it easier to find memory errors (such as writing out of bounds, not freeing memory, etc.).  Use this to your advantage when your program leaks memory or you get erratic behavior that you suspect is due to memory errors.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an application linked with [libgmalloc](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/libgmalloc.3.html).  Those really aren't warnings; they're just telling you it's being used.  This really isn't a programming question...