# error console shows "GuardMalloc"

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

May i know y? it shows error like this(following error).may i know what for it shows me like this

GuardMalloc: Allocations will be placed on 16 byte boundaries.
GuardMalloc:  - Some buffer overruns may not be noticed.
GuardMalloc:  - Applications using vector instructions (e.g., SSE or Altivec) should work.
GuardMalloc: GuardMalloc version 18

With regards

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512691/guardmalloc-what-are-those-warnings-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-them
Please search before you ask.

Answer (score 0):

That looks informational, rather than an error...